# Good IIS7 caching rules?

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis-7

I have been browsing the web looking for caching information but cannot find anything that pinpoints what I am looking for.

I have an ASP.NET website and haven't specifically done anything with caching yet (just relying on IIS7 / ASP.NET defaults at the moment). I don't have much knowledge on caching so I would like a list of things I "should" be doing and also some things that would help the application in general but may not be necessary. My applications memory is running higher than I would like and I believe caching will at least help take some load off the server's memory.

Running: IIS7, ASP.NET2 Application

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this tips [Top 10 Performance Improvements in IIS 7.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.09.iis.aspx)